# how to separate digit contour and others contour using opencv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, contour

I try to change image's background into white but maintain the digit properties. what i trying to do is find the digit contour and change the image into white except the digit. my problem is i don't know how to get the contour. my current progress is i able to draw contour on the image, but it mix up with digit and other object in the image. how to separate digit contour and other contour. i doing this because Tesseract read the image as `0131815` instead of `038586`

can anyone point me to any tutorial even it's in another language. I'll try to convert it into python. my current code:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
bw = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (1, 5))
bw = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel) 

_, contours , _ = cv2.findContours(bw, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

[image: Cropped image with drew contour]

[image: black and white image]

[image: cropped image without contour]

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Please post input sample image

Comment: @gameon67 i added the sample image, please take a look

Comment: You can find vertical black lines separating the digits. And then process each fragment separately. To do so, first binarize it using low threshold and then use blob detection with low inertia ratio to find lines and separate it from black digits.

Comment: @Sushi i can't catch it, what do you mean by low inertia ratio (which method is it)?

Comment: @sone, look at this link: https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/ You have to find blobs that are thin.

Comment: Wow, i think filtering blob by shape could do the works. I'll give a try after back from overseas.. I'll update the results here later

Comment: @Sushi sorry for the late reply.. i manage to solve it by selecting 5 biggest contour ( coz required 5 digit from left) and then use masking to remove unwanted region.. still i think this is not the best approach because the biggest contour could be non digit due to luminance.